# Export to excel error caused by netscaler loadbalncer

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, load-balancer, ntlm

We are curently migrating from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint SE and we are facing strange authenticationg issue on new SHP SE enviroment.

Authentication is **NTLM** and what is happening besides all other small errors in apps is that I am not able to use function **Export to Excel** see [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HheQR.png) we are recieving:

> "Cannoct connect to the server at this time. Changes to your data cannot be saved."

On this new SHP enviroment we are **balancing two SharePoint frontend servers** and in case I set on my machine host enter to eg.:

```
10.20.30.40 documents.our-sharepoint-se.cz
```

Then everything works well. But with loadbalance not.

Also with a standard load balancer, I am able to open a SharePoint List/Library in Excel directly from Excel.

Comment: Have you added the sites URLs in Trusted sites ?

Comment: I tried doing that, but without success.